# How can I create an Excel VBA which will take a selection of objects, (i.e. Text box, Images), groups them if they are ungrouped, and vice versa?

Tags: excel, vba

I am creating an Excel VBA that will group a dynamic selection of objects if they are ungrouped, and ungroup them if they are not group.

This is what I have written below:

```
Sub Macro8()
    
    If Selection.ShapeRange.Group.Select = True Then
        
        Selection.ShapeRange.Ungroup.Select
        
    End If
    
End Sub
```

When i try to compile it, i get the error message in the image above.

Comment: Please attach the screenshot of error